# PHP and MYSQL on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up an amazon server to display my php files for a final for one of my classes.  I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) for setting it up and when I try to run my code I get "Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found".

I tried running `sudo yum install php-pdo`
but it encounters errors saying `Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64` I have read some things saying to change the php.ini file but I am not sure how to do that.

I have also tried this using `mysql_connect`command and get a similar error.

EDIT: I have tried removing php5.3 and it says that it isn't installed so I removed php* and installed php56 and still get the same thing I was getting when I tried to install it before.  As a side note if there is an easier way to run code on a server it doesn't have to be on an Amazon Instance

Comment: It seems like an older version of PHP is still installed and conflicting. Try removing PHP 5.3 and install a fresh copy of PHP 5.6 with the PDO extension as well (unless your app does not support PHP 5.6). You should definitely stay clear of `mysql_` functions. They have been deprecated for years now and are about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release later this year. PDO is the way to go nowadays.

Comment: You probably want `sudo yum install php56-pdo`.

Comment: as you mentioned that you tried `mysql_connect` , Please avoid that always use mysqli_connect(). Try the secure and latest way or switch to `PDO`

Answer (score 4):

This is happened to me also. The thing is that amazon is trying to install php/mysql of older versions . you need to specify which version you need to install. 
to install php-mysql for php 5.6 issue this command.
`sudo yum -y install php56-mysqlnd`

You can install older versions if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

First check how PHP is compiled, simply create a new .php file with in there just:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run that file in your browser and at the top it will tell you wether PHP was compiled with flags like '--enable-pdo=shared', '--with-pdo-mysql=shared', '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared'

If it has been compiled in, you indeed need to enable it in your php.ini file. You can find where that file is with:

```
find / -name 'php.ini'
```

Edit that file with:

```
vi /path/to/that/php.ini
```

Then ensure it contains:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Remember to restart your webserver/php for this change to take effect.